# Changing menu icon in shiny dashboard

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

The following css style corresponds to the menu icon in a shiny dashboard. I want to change it. I tried with `tags$head(tags$style..` in the body, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

```
.main-header .sidebar-toggle:before {
    content: "\f0c9";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `\`:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
      .main-header .sidebar-toggle:before {
        content: "\\f0c7";}')))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also generally wrap the CSS in HTML to prevent escaping of other HTML characters.

Comment: This looks very nice, but I need to replace the menu icon with an image, say `mylogo.png`. How can this be done?

Comment: @panman https://mediatemple.net/blog/tips/creating-implementing-icon-font-tutorial/